# How to make JUnit4 "Wait" for asynchronous job to finish before running tests

Tags: java, android, multithreading, junit4, android-espresso

I am trying to write a test for my android app that communicates with a cloud service.
Theoretically the flow for the test is supposed to be this:

1. Send request to the server in a worker thread
2. Wait for the response from the server
3. Check the response returned by the server

I am trying to use Espresso's `IdlingResource` class to accomplish that but it is not working as expected. Here's what I have so far

My Test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class CloudManagerTest {

FirebaseOperationIdlingResource mIdlingResource;

@Before
public void setup() {
    mIdlingResource = new FirebaseOperationIdlingResource();
    Espresso.registerIdlingResources(mIdlingResource);
}

@Test
public void testAsyncOperation() {
    Cloud.CLOUD_MANAGER.getDatabase().getCategories(new OperationResult<List<Category>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(boolean success, List<Category> result) {
            mIdlingResource.onOperationEnded();
            assertTrue(success);
            assertNotNull(result);
        }
    });
    mIdlingResource.onOperationStarted();
}
}
```

The FirebaseOperationIdlingResource

```
public class FirebaseOperationIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {

private boolean idleNow = true;
private ResourceCallback callback;


@Override
public String getName() {
    return String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());
}

public void onOperationStarted() {
    idleNow = false;
}

public void onOperationEnded() {
    idleNow = true;
    if (callback != null) {
        callback.onTransitionToIdle();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean isIdleNow() {
    synchronized (this) {
        return idleNow;
    }
}

@Override
public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}}
```

When used with Espresso's view matchers the test is executed properly, the activity waits and then check the result.

However plain JUNIT4 assert methods are ignored and JUnit is not waiting for my cloud operation to complete.

Is is possible that `IdlingResource` only work with Espresso methods ? Or am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Theoretically thinking, you can send request -something like- if job is done send `true` otherwise `false` every second and you can hold your job until `true` comes from server by using synchronized methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I use [Awaitility](https://github.com/jayway/awaitility) for something like that.

It has a very good guide, here is the basic idea:

Wherever you need to wait:

```
await().until(newUserIsAdded());
```

elsewhere:

```
private Callable<Boolean> newUserIsAdded() {
      return new Callable<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                  return userRepository.size() == 1; // The condition that must be fulfilled
            }
      };
}
```

I think this example is pretty similar to what you're doing, so save the result of your asynchronous operation to a field, and check it in the `call()` method.

Comment: It worked ! Awaitility is the kind of library I was looking for. Thank you so much !

Comment: For anyone seeing this now, CountDownLatch is probably a better option.

Answer (score 7):

Junit will not wait for async tasks to complete. You can use CountDownLatch to block the thread, until you receive response from server or timeout.

Countdown latch is a simple yet elegant solution and does NOT need an external library. It also helps you focus on the actual logic to be tested rather than over-engineering the async wait or waiting for a response

```
void testBackgroundJob() {


        CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);


        //Do your async job
        Service.doSomething(new Callback() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(){
                ACTUAL_RESULT = SUCCESS;
                latch.countDown(); // notify the count down latch
                // assertEquals(..
            }

        });

        //Wait for api response async
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        assertEquals(expectedResult, ACTUAL_RESULT);

    }
```

Comment: it seems to me more elegant and fo not requires additional libraries

Comment: Note that `await` also supports a timeout and using example above could be used as: `assertTrue(latch.await(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS));` - which tests the return value of `await` and continues (to next assert) if the latched reached zero.  So the three possible outcomes: 1) failed due to timeout; 2) failed due to result not expected; 3) pass as result is expected.